# Шифрование с открытым ключом наоборот c# и php

Tags: php, c#, шифрование, rsa

У меня есть приложение на c# и сервер на php. Приложение должно активироваться платно. После активации на сервер посылается запрос, в параметрах которого есть *mac-id* компьютера, на который сервер отвечает строкой, в которой зашифрован mac-id. Мне надо, чтобы сервер каким-то секретным алгоритмом шифровал этот *mac-id* так, чтобы пользователь мог только **проверить**, правильно ли он зашифрован, а **САМ зашифровать не мог**, дабы программа была более устойчива ко взлому (пользователь не мог сам зашифровать свой *mac-id*) .

**ТО ЕСТЬ:**

1. сервер (на php) шифрует какую-то стоку с помощью секретного ключа и передает ее пользователю
2. пользователь (на c#) может только проверить эту строку на валидность ( с помощью открытого ключа ).

Скорее всего это можно реализовать через rsa-1, но я не очень понимаю как(

Буду рад любым подсказкам)

Comment: Дак если у вас есть сервер у приложения сверяйте просто есть ли в бд к примеру на сервере данный мас-id, если есть в ответе будет активирована платная подписка, если нет то нет, зачем изобретать велосипед.

Comment: @fadey злоумышленники-пираты создадут поддельный сервер, который всегда всё будет активировать, поэтому так нельзя делать

Comment: @fadey, делать это надо при каждом запуске программы - то есть я кладу этот ключ, допустим, в файл, и при каждом запуске программы его проверяю его валидность. И это надо делать оффлайн

Comment: @user188596 так у вас программа не через сервер работает? Т.е у вас сервер только активацией занимается? Один раз прога законнектилась активировалась и все на этом больше сервер ей не нужен?

Comment: @user188596 а вам нужно не шифрование, а цифровая подпись, подтверждающая, что сервер активировал этот mac-id. Информации о цифровых подписях навалом в соответствующей литературе

Comment: @fadey да, сервер занимается только активацией

Answer (score 1):

```
    internal static class  RSAcrypt
   {
       private static RSAParameters _publickey;
       private static RSAParameters _privatekey;
       /// <summary>
       /// Публичный код для шифрования
       /// </summary>
       private static string _publicKey;
       /// <summary>
       /// Частный ключ для дешефровки
       /// </summary>
       private static string _privateKey;


       public enum keySizes
       {
           Size512 = 512,
           Size1024 = 1024,
           Size2048 = 2048,
           Size952 = 952,
           Size136 = 136
       };

       /// <summary>
       /// Частный ключ для дешефровки
       /// </summary>
       public static string PrivateKey
       {
           get { return _privateKey; }
           set { _privateKey = value; }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Публичный код для шифрования
       /// </summary>
       public static string PublicKey
       {
           get { return _publicKey; }
           set { _publicKey = value; }
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Метод генерирует два ключа публичный и часный и сохраняет их файлы
       /// </summary>
       public static void GenerateKeys() //создание ключей 
       {
           try
           {
               if (Directory.Exists(GlobalConfig.TempFolder) == false)
               {
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(GlobalConfig.Data);
                   Directory.CreateDirectory(GlobalConfig.TempFolder);
               }
               using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider((int) keySizes.Size2048))
               {
                   if (File.Exists(GlobalConfig.PublicKey))
                       File.Delete(GlobalConfig.PublicKey);
                   if (File.Exists(GlobalConfig.PrivateKey))
                       File.Delete(GlobalConfig.PrivateKey);

                   rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
                   PublicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
                   File.WriteAllText(GlobalConfig.PublicKey, PublicKey);

                   PrivateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
                   File.WriteAllText(GlobalConfig.PrivateKey, PrivateKey);
               }
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               //TODO:: обработчик ошибок
           }
       }

       public static void GetKeys()
       {
           if (File.Exists(GlobalConfig.PublicKey))
           {
               PublicKey = File.ReadAllText(GlobalConfig.PublicKey);
           }
           if (File.Exists(GlobalConfig.PrivateKey))
           {
               PrivateKey = File.ReadAllText(GlobalConfig.PrivateKey);
             //  File.Delete(GlobalConfig.PrivateKey);
           }   


       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Метод дешифрует используя Часный ключ
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="text">текс для шифрования</param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       public static string Decrypt(string text)
       {
           try
           {
               byte[] decrContent = null;

               RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
               rsa.FromXmlString(PrivateKey);
               decrContent = rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(text), true);
               return _toString(decrContent);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(e.Message, @"Ошибка дешифровки", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               throw;
           }
       }
       /// <summary>
       /// Метод меняет кодировку
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="decrContent">массив байтов</param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       private static string _toString(byte[] decrContent)
       {
           return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrContent);
       }
       /// <summary>
       /// Метод переводит String в байты
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="text"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       private static byte[] _toByte(string text)
       {
           return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Метод шифрудет данные с указаным публичным  ключем
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="text">Текс для расшидрования</param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       public static string Encrypt(string text)
       {
           try
           {
               byte[] encContent = null;

               RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
               rsa.FromXmlString(PublicKey);
               encContent = rsa.Encrypt(_toByte(text),true);
               return Convert.ToBase64String(encContent);
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               Console.WriteLine(e);
               throw;
           }
       }

   }
```

**RSA шифрование**

Comment: Шифруете с public ключем , дешифруете с Private

Comment: А не подскажите, как метод encrypt на php переписать?

Comment: и еще, мне надо ровно наоборот - ШИФРОВАТЬ с private, а ДЕШИФРОВАТЬ с public

Comment: я не совсем понимаю логику если вы хотите зарегистрировать пользователя по его mac-id то получив mac-id шифруете с помощью публичного ключа и отсылаете на сервер

Comment: нет, на сервере я шифрую его mac-id (с помощью приватного ключа, чтобы левый пользователь зашифровать не мог) , а далее отсылаю результат ему. Дальше юзер проверяет, правильно ли зашифрован его mac-id(с помощью публичного ключа), и если правильно - программа активирована.

Comment: "чтобы левый пользователь зашифровать не мог" , как вы это понимаете ? пользователь что сам выберает свой mac-id и в

Comment: нет, но надо сделать так, чтобы только сервер имел право шифровать mac-id, а пользователь - только проверять, правильно ли зашифровано

Comment: ну дело в том что приватный ключ содержит в себе публичный ключ, следуя вашей логике пользователь может вытащить из приватного ключа публичный, мне не понятны ваши опасения по поводу шифрования на стороне клиента,тогда используйте базу данных